# apply the custom function on rows which takes two lists as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
col1          col2
[1,2]         [3,4]
[5,6]         [7,8]
[9,5]         [1,3]
[8,4]         [3,6]
```

and I have a function f which takes two list inputs and returns a single value. I want to add the column as col3 and apply the function with col1 and col2 values. the output of the function will be col3 values, so the final data frame would look like,

```
 col1          col2     col3
[1,2]         [3,4]      3
[5,6]         [7,8]      5
[9,5]         [1,3]      8
[8,4]         [3,6]      9
```

Using a for loop and passing list values each time I can calculate the col3 values. but the execution time will be longer. Looking for pythonic way to do the task more efficiently.

Comment: Is possible see your function?

Comment: @jezrael actually its python built-in function -- its dtw.distance

Answer (score 1):

Working with lists in pandas is not good vectorized, possible solution with list comprehension:

```
df['col3'] = [func(a, b) for a,b in zip(df.col1, df.col2)]
```

Pandas `apply` solution (should be slowier):

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x.col1, x.col2), axis=1)
```

---

But if function should be vectorized and same length of list in columns maybe is possible rewrite it to `numpy`.

If not, maybe rewritten function to `numba` should help.

Performance with custom function:

```
#[40000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

#sample function
def func(x, y):
    return min(x + y)


In [144]: %timeit df['col31'] = [func(a, b) for a,b in zip(df.col1, df.col2)]
39.6 ms ± 331 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [145]: %timeit df['col32'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x.col1, x.col2), axis=1)
2.25 s ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```